# More efficient time delta calculation python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

Sorry I'm new to python.

I have a dataframe of entities that log values once a month.  For each unique entity in my dataframe, I locate the max value then locate the max value's corresponding month. Using the max value month, a time delta between each other unique entity's months and the max month can be calculated in days. This works for small dataframes.

I know my loop is not performant and can't scale to larger dataframes(e.g., 3M rows (+156MB)). After weeks of research I've gathered that my loop is degenerate and feel there is a numpy solution or something more pythonic. Can someone see a more performant approach to calculating this time delta in days?

I've tried various value.shift(x) calculations in a lambda function, but the peak value is not consistent.  I've also tried calculating more columns to minimize my loop calculations.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'], 'month': ['10/31/2018','11/30/2018','12/31/2018','1/31/2019','1/31/2009','2/28/2009','3/31/2009','8/31/2011','9/30/2011','10/31/2011','11/30/2011','12/31/2011'], 'value':['80','600','500','400','150','300','100','200','250','300','200','175'], 'month_number': ['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','1','2','3','4','5']})

df['month'] = df['month'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

for entity in set(df['entity']):
    # set peak value
    peak_value = df.loc[df['entity'] == entity, 'value'].max()
    # set peak value date
    peak_date = df.loc[(df['entity'] == entity) & (df['value'] == peak_value), 'month'].min()
    # subtract peak date from current date
    delta = df.loc[df['entity'] == entity, 'month'] - peak_date
    # update days_delta with delta in days
    df.loc[df['entity'] == entity, 'days_delta'] = delta
```

RESULT:

```
entity   month   value   month_number   days_delta
A       2018-10-31   80    1    0 days
A       2018-11-30    600    2  30 days
A       2018-12-31  500 3   61 days
A       2019-01-31  400 4   92 days
B       2009-01-31  150 1   -28 days
B       2009-02-28  300 2   0 days
B       2009-03-31  100 3   31 days
C       2011-08-31  200 1   -61 days
C       2011-09-30  250 2   -31 days
C       2011-10-31  300 3   0 days
C       2011-11-30  200 4   30 days
C       2011-12-31  175 5   61 days
```

Comment: `df['month'].astype('datetime64[D]')` creates a `numpy` efficient array.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

First let's also make sure `value` is numeric

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entity':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C'],
    'month': ['10/31/2018','11/30/2018','12/31/2018','1/31/2019',
              '1/31/2009','2/28/2009','3/31/2009','8/31/2011',
              '9/30/2011','10/31/2011','11/30/2011','12/31/2011'],
    'value':['80','600','500','400','150','300','100','200','250','300','200','175'],
    'month_number': ['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','1','2','3','4','5']
})

df['month'] = df['month'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
```

---

#### `transform` and `idxmax`

```
max_months = df.groupby('entity').value.transform('idxmax').map(df.month)
df.assign(days_delta=df.month - max_months)

   entity      month  value month_number days_delta
0       A 2018-10-31     80            1   -30 days
1       A 2018-11-30    600            2     0 days
2       A 2018-12-31    500            3    31 days
3       A 2019-01-31    400            4    62 days
4       B 2009-01-31    150            1   -28 days
5       B 2009-02-28    300            2     0 days
6       B 2009-03-31    100            3    31 days
7       C 2011-08-31    200            1   -61 days
8       C 2011-09-30    250            2   -31 days
9       C 2011-10-31    300            3     0 days
10      C 2011-11-30    200            4    30 days
11      C 2011-12-31    175            5    61 days
```

Comment: piRSquared's solution ran in ~4 minutes on 3.7M records. I changed the df.assign(...) to df['time_delta'] = df.month - max_months so the column would be permanent in my dataframe.